# add all textfield values to a single list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, textfield

I need a little help,

I create TextFields dynamically and I want to add the TextField values to a list,

Here is how I create TextFields dynamically,

```
List<TextEditingController> descriptionControllers = List.generate(11,(_) => TextEditingController(),);
```

Here is how I display all these TextFields in a DataTable

```
DataCell(Container(
                width: 150,
                child: TextField(
                  minLines: 1,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  ),
                  controller: descriptionControllers[index],
                ))),
```

Here is how I am collecting the values of all these TextFields,

```
void collectData() {
  descriptions.clear();
  for (int index = 0; index < descriptionControllers.length; index++) {
    descriptions.add(descriptionControllers[index].text);
    print(descriptions);
  }
}
```

but the problem is, when i print the data, it creates 11 Lists because I have 11 TextFields but I dont want that, I want a single list with all these values in it.

here is the printed lists,

```
I/flutter (29182): [Just]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To, Check]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To, Check, The ]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To, Check, The , Whole ]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To, Check, The , Whole , List]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To, Check, The , Whole , List, ]
I/flutter (29182): [Just, To, Check, The , Whole , List, , ]
```

how can i add all these values to a single list, instead of all these many lists.

Comment: You only have one list. You just happen to print that list after every addition..

Comment: but if i want to display this list on a page, wouldnt it repeat after every addition?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that. I only see one list, and I don't get why you think there are 11 lists. It looks fine to me

Comment: My mistake. Thank you so much for the clarifications. if i want to print them, i need to use an index to not repeat the list. Appreciate the help